# Calculate sum of specific rows using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sum, rows

I need to calculate the sum of specific rows in my dataframe

for example, `Nombre de reboot`, `Passage en mode privé`, `Passage en mode public`, `Nombre de Kilomètres parcourus`, `Heures de roulage`,`Temps de trajet`..

I tested this **code** on the first three rows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('mycollected_data1.xlsx')


print (df.iloc[:3, df.columns.get_indexer(['Valeurs','Valeurs.1','Valeurs.2'])])
a = df.iloc[1:3, [1,2,3]].sum()

print ('a\n', a)
```

this is the **output**:

```
    Valeurs Valeurs.1 Valeurs.2
0       3         5         0
1       2         1         1
2       0         0         0
a
 Valeurs      2.0
Valeurs.1    1.0
Valeurs.2    1.0
dtype: float64
```

**desired output:**

```
        Valeurs Valeurs.1 Valeurs.2   sum
    0       3         5         0       8
    1       2         1         1       4
    2       0         0         0       0
```

how can I make it calculate the sum of specific given rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `axis=1` in your sum function

Original `df`

```
df
   Valeurs  Valeurs.1  Valeurs.2
0        3          5          0
1        2          1          1
2        0          0          0


cols = ['Valeurs','Valeurs.1','Valeurs.2']

df['sum'] = df.loc[0:2, cols].sum(axis=1)
df # final df

   Valeurs  Valeurs.1  Valeurs.2  sum
0        3          5          0    8
1        2          1          1    4
2        0          0          0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,

we can use `.sum` while specifying the axis as 1 to work row wise.

```
cols = ['Valeurs','Valeurs.1','Valeurs.2']

df['sum'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)

print(df)

   Valeurs  Valeurs.1  Valeurs.2  sum
0        3          5          0    8
1        2          1          1    4
2        0          0          0    0
```

edit, if you need to access certain rows you can use the `.loc` function as @quant has

```
row_start = 0
row_end = 2
df.loc[row_start:row_end,cols].sum(axis=1)
```

Just as a word of advice, it seems like you have repeated column names with similar datatypes, i would first clean your column headings and then melt your dataframe to get a tabular model.

Comment: thank you, but how can I specify the row that I need to work on ?

Comment: as in you only want to sum a certain index location? will the other values just be NaN?if so you can use `loc.`